# Error using .* Matrix dimensions must agree?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm new to MATLAB, and I'm trying to apply a high pass butterworth filter to my data images. I'm getting the following error:

```
Error using  `.*`  Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

Here's my code:

```
function[]=Preprocessing()
I = imread('Photo0029.jpg');
imshow(I);
imDouble=im2double(I);
fftlogim=fft(log(imDouble+0.01))   
f=butterhp(I,15,1);
c=fftlogim.*f;
h=real(ifft(c));
figure,ishow(h);
h1=exp(h);
ifftshow(h1);
```

and here's the `butterhp` function:

```
function[out]=butterhp(im,d,n)
h=size(im,1);
w=size(im,2);
[x,y]=meshgrid(-floor(w/2):floor(w-1)/2,-floor(h/2):floor(h-1)/2);
out=1./(1.+(d./(x.^2+y.^2).^0.5).^(2*n));
end
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: You should format your code in the post so it's easier to read and understand.

Comment: Simple: your matrix dimensions are not equal. Try multiplying two equal sized matrices instead. Also: there's rather a few questions with this title already, I couldn't remove the MATLAB from it without the system saying so. Please search first.

Comment: Let me guess, your photo is RGB? Do you need to keep it in RGB, or is processing it in grayscale ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your input image `I` is a color image (RGB), the array `I` is three-dimensional: *`width`-by-`height`-by-`3`*, because for each pixel you need three values: red, green and blue. The output of `butterhp`, however, is always *`width`-by-`height`*, so you are trying to multiply a 2D-array times a 3D-array, which fails of course.

Often, processing in grayscale is faster and gets quite good results. To do that, convert the image to grayscale after loading using [`rgb2gray`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html):

```
imGrayScale = rgb2gray(I);
```

If you want to stick with RGB and process each color channel independently, you can replace your multiplication by [`bsxfun`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), which applies the element-wise operation (here: `@times`, i.e. element-wise multiplication) to all elements of `fftlogim` and `f`, but "implicitly expanding the dimensions". That means the *`w`-by-`h`-by-`1`* matrix is automatically converted to *`w`-by-`h`-by-`3`* so both arrays can be multiplied.

```
c = bsxfun(@times, fftlogim, f);
```

Comment: Thanks ! i've already solved the issue. I split the RGB channels and multiplied seperately . thanks again !